# Where does jetty searches log4j configuraion for my application?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, jetty

First of all I want to say that I mean my web application logs(rather than jetty own logs).

I am writing web application(`jetty`+`spring`+`hibernate`)
Recently I had knew that I can place `log4j.properties` outside the web application (outside the war file). As I understand `jetty` serches logs by rule. At first in place A, then in place B....and eventually inside application.

If I right, please answer where can I find this sequence ?

Comment: http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/example-logging-log4j.html

Comment: @David Pérez Cabrera I have seen this article but I didn't catch that there was written about application log. quote - **....so that Log4j controls the output of logging events produced by Jetty.**

Comment: please, answer, Am I correct?